# how to pass the data from one component to another in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

*so what I am trying to do is, I want to pass the data collected in the header search bar to another component so that I can use it on that component as a query for the API I am going to use*

the header component:

```
import ImageSearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ImageSearch';

import './Header.css'

function Header() {

    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    

    return (
        <div className="Header">
            {/* LOGO */}
            <div className="branding">
                <ImageSearchIcon className="branding__logo" fontSize="large"/>
                <h1>Image Finder</h1>
            </div>

            {/* Search Bar */}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" id="header__searchbar" placeholder="Search For Images" value={query} onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
            </form>
            

            {/* USER ICON */}
            <img className="user__image" src="https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/150-1503945_transparent-user-png-default-user-image-png-png.png" alt="user__image" />


        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

the Second component:

```
import './Imagelist.css'

const Imagelist = () => {

    
    return (
        <div className="Imagelist">
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Imagelist
```

Comment: btw I am a beginner in stack overflow and I have not asked many questions so if I have done something wrong please forgive me

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data between parent and child components in React using `props`(think of `props` as the parameters of components).

This is how passing `props` looks like:

```js
// Header component

const Header = () => {
  // ... your logic
  return (
    <ImageList myProp={query} />
  );
}

// ImageList component
const ImageList = ({ myProp }) => {
  // now you can use myProp inside this component
};
```

You can get more information on props and React in general [here](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling) (as mentioned by @Robfz): If you might use the prop in other components again (or also if your child component is very far from the parent), you could look into [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). This would allow you to pass your props down without having to pass it through every child in between.

Answer (score 0):

[Lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the parent component that a) performs the API request and manages the data, and b) renders both `Header` and `ImageList`.

`App` maintains the main data state. It passes a handler to `Header` that is called when the `Header` button is clicked. When that handler is called the API is called and image JSON returned. The `App` state is then updated with that (parsed) data.

`ImageList` receives this data through a prop "images". It uses map to get the `src` value from each returned object and return a new image.

Here's a brief working example explaining how I would approach this problem.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Sample JSON data
const json = '[{ "src": "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/77aa77/fff&text=Image" },{ "src": "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/7777aa/fff&text=Image" },{ "src": "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/aa7777/fff&text=Image" }]';

// Using a mock API to return some JSON
// after a two-second wait
function mockApi() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(json), 2000);
  });
}

// ImageList receives an array of objects from App
// and maps over it creating a new image on each iteration
function ImageList({ images }) {
  return (
    <div className="imagelist">
      {images.map(img => <img src={img.src} />)}
    </div>
  )
}

// App passes in the `handleUpdate` handler as a prop
function Header({ handleUpdate }) {

  // Header maintains its own state for the input
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  // When the input changes we update the state
  function handleChange(e) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  // When the button is clicked the `handleUpdate`
  // handler passed down from App is called with
  // the current state
  function handleClick() {
    handleUpdate(input);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Search: <input type="text" value={input} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Search</button>
    </div>
  );

}

function App() {

  // Maintains the image state
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  // When the button in Header is clicked this
  // handler is called. It makes an API call with the
  // value: fetch(`${endpoint}/${value}`), and then
  // sets the state with the data
  function handleUpdate(value) {
    console.log(`Query: ${value}`);
    mockApi()
      .then(json => JSON.parse(json))
      .then(data => setImages(data)); 
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header handleUpdate={handleUpdate} />
      <ImageList images={images} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```